# Two login pages with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, authentication, acl, cakephp-2.4

I have an app that requires login for users. However, to keep matters simple, we are only supplying the user with a unique code, so that they just enter the code and that code logs them in. This code is only valid for two weeks, and will never be repeated.

However, our Admin also needs to log in but the admin requires a username and password.

How will I modify the `AppController` to allow for both logins? I'm using the AclExtras plugin for Authentication

The one login is located under `APP/Users/enter` (for the users), the other is under `APP/Users/login` (for the admins)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement a custom Auth adapter that checks for the token. No need to have a separate action except you explicitly want that.

Cake is iterating over all loaded auth adapters so you can have username and password and the token in the same form. If the regular form adapter returns false but the token auth adapter true the user is logged in.

Check [the books section about auth](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers). It has all information you need to understand what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a simple if/else in your `AppController` checking if the field for unique code is passed, if not then you can implement login with username/password. In all other cases you can implement login by unique code.

Comment: Mind adding a code sample? I've added an if statement, and just changed the login action depending on what page is selected. - However it's not working.